# Bootstrap tooltip issue

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, twitter-bootstrap

Whatever I do my tooltip just shows beneath the relevant link.

I have the following style in my head:

```
<style>
/* Tooltip on top */
.test + .tooltip.top > .tooltip-arrow {
    border-top: 5px solid green;
}
</style>
```

Within the body I have:

```
<a class="test" href="#" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="top" title="ROUND">R</a>
```

At the bottom of everything I have:

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('[data-toggle="tooltip"]').tooltip();
});
</script>
```

I was trying to use the guide from:

```
http://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap/tryit.asp?filename=trybs_ref_js_tooltip_css&stacked=h
```

Any hints or tips would be great :)

Comment: Could you provide which  cdn you use ?

Comment: Bootstrap v3.3.6 (http://getbootstrap.com) - Is this what you mean? sorry.

Comment: Ur code is fine.. [Bootstrap CDN](http://getbootstrap.com/getting-started/).. U have to include **SCRIPT** and **CSS** to your page and it's gonna work => [CodePen](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/ORgdQb)

Comment: Tried it but no joy but I am tired so will see if im doing something silly in the morning.  Thank you for your help :)

Comment: btw i think .tooltip-inner class is what you want for styling tooltip

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to use the **container** option of tooltip with the **body** value :

```
 <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-container="body" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="left" title="Tooltip on left" >Tooltip on left</button>
```

Take a look at the options array in the official doc : http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#tooltips

Comment: Many thanks for the answer but still the same result with it just sitting below the button :/ .Is obviously something i'm doing wrong so back to the drawing board lol

Comment: Look at the z-index value of your link if you have put one and decrease it. Make a codePen or a public page so it will more easier for us to help you ;-)

Comment: No z-index. Never used code pen so will try that tomorrow:)